# When remove Breadcrumb from site it remove Page Title on catalog pages

Tags: magento-1.9, breadcrumbs, page-title, meta-title

I have tried to remove breadcrumb from the whole site using below code.

```
<reference name="root">
    <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</reference>
```

Or just

```
<remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
```

When put this code to `local.xml` it remove `Page Title` on `catalog Pages`

Is there any other safe way to remove breadcrumb from the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `safe` way to remove breadcrumb.`unsetchild` instead of `remove`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">            
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
        </reference>       
    </default> 
</layout>
```